# Extremal subject to integral constraint

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am trying to find the extremal of

$$I[y] = \int_{-1}^{1}{y}dx$$

Subject to the constraint

$$\int_{-1}^{1}y^2+y’^2dx=1$$

And boundary conditions $y(-1)=y(1)=0$.

I used the Lagrange multiplier and Euler Lagrange equations to find that the general solution is

$$y=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+\frac{1}{2\lambda}$$

But when trying to solve for the constants I’m getting really awkward and messy values involving exponentials. Can someone point me in the right direction?